# Firebase In-App Messaging cause java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (21.4.1)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-in-app-messaging

Getting runtime exception while trying to use Firebase Auth and In-App Messaging. As soon as I try to authenticate user with Firebase getting following exception -

```
I/FIAM.Headless: Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Installation ID dT********Gl49TUSZRKMx

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: buzz.anusmarak, PID: 24274
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (21.4.1).
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:534)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$3.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest.getDefaultInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:915)
        at com.google.firestore.v1.FirestoreGrpc.getListenMethod(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:408)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:61)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.Datastore.createWatchStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:115)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:280)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:108)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:436)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$2.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:322)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:229)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get message info for com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.java:62)
        at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory$CompositeMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:143)
        at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory.createSchema(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:55)
        at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:93)
        at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:107)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.makeImmutable(GeneratedMessageLite.java:171)
        at com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:911)
        at com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest.getDefaultInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:915) 
        at com.google.firestore.v1.FirestoreGrpc.getListenMethod(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:408) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:61) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.Datastore.createWatchStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:115) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:167) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:280) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:108) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:436) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$2.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:322) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:229) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest.dynamicMethod(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:903)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.dynamicMethod(GeneratedMessageLite.java:252)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.buildMessageInfo(GeneratedMessageLite.java:280)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.java:60)
            ... 25 more
```

Following dependencies are being used -

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //firebase Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1'
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'
    //Firebase Storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    //Firebase Cloud Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
    //Firebase In-App Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:19.1.1'

    //AdsMob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'

    //Preferences Screen
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'

    //Kotlin extension
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'

    //circular images
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.2.0'

    //lottie animation
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1'

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.5"

    //Joda Time
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.6'

    //Image Cropper
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

    //Calendar View
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.7.0'

    //Work Manager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0"

    //Guava error
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

    //Custom Preference Library
    implementation 'com.takisoft.preferencex:preferencex:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.takisoft.preferencex:preferencex-datetimepicker:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.takisoft.preferencex:preferencex-colorpicker:1.1.0'
    //https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix/wiki/Preference-types#timepickerpreference

    //Color Picker
    implementation 'com.github.rtugeek:colorseekbar:1.7.7'
    //https://github.com/rtugeek/ColorSeekBar
}
```

If I remove following dependency from build.gradle file

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.1.1'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:19.1.1'
> ```

**then exception is resolved**, but I want to use Firebase In-App Messaging feature in my app. Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There's some bugs included with the updated in-app messaging library and this cause the exception when used. You can go with the previous version library to avoid the exception but I can't guarantee you that the previous version library still functions. Some of the effected new version libraries are in-app messaging and remote config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore
```

Seems like bug for this version. You can raise an issue [**@Google**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533) or [**@Github**](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/new/choose) for this.

> The Android Issue Tracker contains a list of pending technical tasks
> across a variety of topics, information relevant to those tasks, and
> information about progress on those tasks, including which ones might
> get worked on in the short term.

You should upgrade your [**FirebaseUI for Android**](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/) version. FirebaseUI for Android **`v6.3.0`** is a minor release containing new features and bug fixes. Read [**v6.3.0**](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases/tag/6.3.0).

```
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.3.0'
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.3.0'
```

**FYI**

If same issues still coming then You can downgrade your version for now

```
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.1.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:19.1.0'
```

Comment: upgrading  FirebaseUI version to 6.3.0 worked for me, thank you and cheers :)